# Reading JSON input in spring MVC application - Issue with emaild

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

Am trying to pass emaild in my request params..

While reading it in my controller class am getting below exception..

```
[ Catch Exception :  Error Message: Unexpected end-of-input: was expecting closing quote for a string value
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@200a200a; line: 1, column: 195] ]


http://localhost:8080/appln/fetch/
ipdata={"date":"2013-10-05","emailId":"my.email.com@gmail.com"}
```

if i have the emailId as "myemailcom@gmailcom" ..it works well...

My Controller code looks kind of ..

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(ipdataString,InputRequestBean.class);
```

--

What am getting is...
{"date":"2013-10-05","emailId":"my

and my bean is

```
public class InputRequestBean {
    private String date;
    private String emailId;
    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    /**
     * @param date the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    /**
     * @return the emailId
     */
    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }
    /**
     * @param emailId the emailId to set
     */
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your `InputRequestBean` class and the actual JSON string you get.

Comment: What am getting is...                                                                   {"date":"2013-10-05","emailId":"my                                              and my bean is

Comment: You can edit your question, you know?

Comment: Thank you..added it the question itself

Comment: If the JSON you receive from your service is like what you show in `ipdata`, then this should work fine.

Comment: Hi Sotrios,                                                                    The service layer is not recieving the whole of the ipdata from the web UI..the emailId is getting broken after the '.'

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with the `ObjectMapper`. Show us where the data is sent to service layer and how it is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some googling..and this is the fix that worked..

@RequestMapping(value = "/appln/fetch/{ipdata:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

Spring Doc...: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex